# Что мне нужно вписать в форме action=""

Tags: html, python, django

Есть Функция и шаблон для добовления комеентарив но она не работает подозреваю что проблемма в action или в том что функция GetComments не обрабатываеться

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import CommentModel, Articles



class ArticlesList(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'



class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/post.html'

    def GetComments(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = CommentForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                # Сохранение формы
                form.save()

                # Редирект на ту же страницу
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

        else:
        # метод GET

            form = CommentForm()

            # Получение всех имен из БД.
            comm = CommentModel.objects.all()

        # И добавляем names в контекст, чтобы плучить к ним доступ в шаблоне
        return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'form': form, 'comments': comm})
```

post.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>


    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {% if comm %}
        {% for comm in comments %}
          {{ comm.WhoAreYou }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    WhoAreYou = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import CommentModel


class CommentForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = ('WhoAreYou',)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать чтобы после запроса обрабатывались две функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score -1):

В action записывается имя файла-обработчика. После сабмита формы данные из неё будут отправлены указанным методом в этот файл.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Обратите внимание на теги вопроса. WSGI-приложения работаю иначе.